# Webpack doesn't generate app.bundle.css

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following webpack file, however, when I run npm run dev the name.bundle.css file doesn't get generated: (no errors either)

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/'),
    entry: {
        app: './index.jsx'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/assets/'),
        publicPath: '/assets/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use:  ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    }],
                }),
            },
            {
              test: /\.jsx|js$/,
              exclude: [/node-modules/],
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "babel-loader",
                  options: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
              use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [ 
            path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].bundle.css'
        })
    ]
}
```

my CSS folder is:

```
CSS
    - app.scss
    COMPONENTS
        comp1.scss
        comp2.scss
```

it works this way "import styles from './css/app.scss';" but I would expect this to generate a app.bundle.css:

```
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: '[name].bundle.css'
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 rules for both css and sass.

I think in your case you only need one:

```
test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
     use: [{
         loader: "css-loader"
     }, {
         loader: "sass-loader"
     }],
     fallback: "style-loader"
})
```

and like you said, you should import the scss files in the js files `import './css/app.scss'`